# What is better "lives up to his name" or "just like its name"?

Tags: sentence-construction, gerunds

What of this two sentences is better and doesn't sound weird?

1. > "Transverse foramen", just like its name, says that the foramen moving across this bone.
2. > "Transverses foramen", its name lives up to his name, and says that the foramen moving across this bone.

If you have a better option, please, kindly let me know it.

Comment: Neither one. 1) is incomplete. 2) needs a conjunction between "foramen" and "its".

Comment: Can you help me please, because I don't know what you mean. Do you mean to the word "and" for example?

Comment: I think the term should be "Transverse foramen" (without s on tranverse) which is a part of a bone in the spine.

Comment: You're right. I edited it. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. "Transverses foramen", just like its name *implies*, says that the foramen *moves* across this bone.

and

> 2. "Transverses foramen" lives up to *its* name, and says that the foramen *moves* across this bone.

In both, the phrase "says that the foramen moving across this bone" needs a verb.

In 1. I added *implies*, this is an improvement but could be left out.

And in 2, the first comma is not needed so I would just remove it.